# NLTK Named entity recognition is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have created a dataframe called **result**. Each cell contains long text with names in it. I need to identify the names. I have used the below code:

```
import nltk

for col in result:
    for i in range(result.shape[0]):
       print(result[col][i])
       if not result[col][i]:
           continue
       else:
           entities = nltk.ne_chunk(result[col][i])
           for entity in entities:
               print(entity)
               if type(entity) == nltk.tree.Tree: 
                   print(entity)
```

the error that I'm getting is

```
ERROR:root:message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-99-8b2514840dbb>", line 10, in <module>
   entities = nltk.ne_chunk(result[col][1])
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
    packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 186, in ne_chunk
       return chunker.parse(tagged_tokens)
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
    packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 128, in parse
       tagged = self._tagger.tag(tokens)
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 64, in tag
       tags.append(self.tag_one(tokens, i, tags))
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 84, in tag_one
       tag = tagger.choose_tag(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 652, in choose_tag
       featureset = self.feature_detector(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 699, in feature_detector
       return self._feature_detector(tokens, index, history)
  File "C:\Users\II00083764\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\nltk\chunk\named_entity.py", line 59, in _feature_detector
       pos = simplify_pos(tokens[index][1])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Hi, can you add the full error log? That will indicate which lines is throwing this error

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen I have added the error

Comment: What is the output of the `print(result[col][i])` ?